# Flask-login loaded a wrong user

Tags: flask, flask-login

I'm building a web app with Flask-login, but sometimes I find myself logged in as another user instead of myself.

It happens if I passed the "remember=True" parameter during my last logging in, but not always.

I'm wondering whether it's a bug in Flask-login or just a bug in my code. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does you login code look like?

Comment: Flask-Login uses a userid stored in the session to identify who is logged in-- if you're developing it's probably just picking up the userid which you set at an earlier stage.  Just change your SECRET_KEY and it'll invalidate all the sessions and you'll be on a clean slate.

Answer (score 1):

As @doobeh mentioned in a comment earlier -- the way Flask-Login works is by grabbing user information from session data.

If your session information gets messed up somehow, this could cause problems for you.

To wipe your sessions, chance your `SECRET_KEY` setting to a new random string, then restart your Flask service -- this will invalidate all old sessions and force users to re-authenticate.

This should do it!

Comment: what are the scenarios when flask session information can get messed up? I am not using any parameter for caching requests, still getting this problem

Comment: it happened for me when I recreated my user database after changing some tables. I was still logged in, but as a secondary user